# Angular: add slash "/" in the input type text for date field

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Hello all i am new to angular-js, 
I want to add slash in Input type=text.

I don't want to use any packages like angular-ui or input type Date.

I want to add `/` as user enters the date like after two digits and then after 5th i.e `12/12/2012` in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. 
I have tried the following code. Please help me where I am wrong.

```
@component({
selector: 'exp-basic-identity',
  template: `
    <input placeholder="Date of Birth(MM/DD/YYYY)"
                           ([ngModel])="formGroup.controls['dob'].value"
                                           formControlName="dob"
                                           (input) = "onKey($event.target.value)"
                                           [type]="'text'"
                                           [animatePlaceholder]="true" i18n>'


export class ExpBasicIdentityComponent implements OnInit {
  public formGroup: FormGroup;
 key: string;
  event: KeyboardEvent;
 onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let DobVal = this.formGroup.controls['dob'].value;
        if (DobVal.length === 2 || DobVal.length === 5 ) {
            DobVal = DobVal + '/';
        }

    }
}
```

I didnt find any resources in the angular.js 
all i got was in jquery or in javascript. 
So tried to implement in that manner.

Now the thing is i am getting "/" when i saw in debugging [image: image of slash added - debugging]

How can i add slash automatically while user gives input ? 
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you never set the value with the the slash. `this.formGroup.controls['dob'].setValue(value)`

Comment: @LLai can you please explain it with example or JSfiddle ??

Comment: @LLai alright i got it. 
but now the next problem if i do backspace "/" is not deleted with backspace ? 
what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

> Now the thing is i am getting "/" when i saw in debugging

This is because you are at point `A` which means code at point `B` has already executed. The `/` is coming from the code you wrote at point `B`

[image]

Comment: @ basarat yeah i got that. but it is not reflecting to the input field. 
and moreover this is not my doubt. i want to know how to add slash while user gives input. ?? 
can you help me out in that ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved using following code. 
Thanks to @LLai

```
 onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let DobVal = this.formGroup.controls['dob'].value;
        if (DobVal.length === 2 || DobVal.length === 5 ) {
            this.formGroup.controls['dob'].setValue(DobVal + '/');
        }
    }
```

When I am using clearing the letter by BACKSPACE, After the /, It is not clearing. Is there any way I can avoid this condition ??

[image: Latest Output]

Can anyone help with this one please ?
Thanks in advance.